# How to get contract address with Contract Name

Tags: etherscan, addresses, erc-721, nft

I am trying to pull NFT address by providing their name. For instance to get CryptoPunks address :  I will pass 'cryptopunks' and get '0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb' as a result.

Does anyone have any clue on this?

Comment: You may need blockchain explorers or NFT marketplaces' APIs. However, there isn't a single universal API or method for this because different NFT projects may be deployed on different blockchain networks, each with its own set of tools and APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no true registry that maps any human-readable names to smart contract addresses, so what you are asking is impossible.

If you need a list of well-known smart contracts you need to assemble this data by hand.